# Django - User model last active column

Tags: django, django-models, django-users

How can I make a column in my AbstractUser Model that has the date of the last time the user logged in the app?

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    is_buyer = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_merchant = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    pin = models.CharField(max_length=6, blank=True)
    TwoFA = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    image = models.ImageField(blank=True)

    date_created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

Comment: Can you show your custom user model? `AbstractBaseUser` which `AbstractUser` inherits from already has a `last_login` field

Comment: Your model should already have a `last_login` field containing the data you want

Comment: Should I do this >   last_active = models.last_active()   ?

Comment: You shouldn't need to do anything to your model, it will already have that column. Access `user.last_login`, please show where you need to access the last login value

Comment: Just be wary that last active and last login can mean two different things if you're using persistent sessions.